# MPD - Hosting a server then playing music from a web client

Tags: audio, music, audio-streaming, music-management, mpd

I have a computer at home which runs `mpd`, and I have a client on that computer (locally) that can play music to my headphones.
I want to be able to use a web client to access my `mpd` server, and then play that music in the audio device of the client that's using the web client.
So far I've tried `ympd` to serve up a web page, and I can access that from different devices in my network and control `mpd` from there. But the problem arrives when I try to play the music - it plays into my headphones at the computer that hosts `mpd`!

I suspect this is a problem with my configuration, so how do I configure my server to stream audio to a client's audio device? (If that matters I have `pulseaudio` on the computer that hosts `mpd` and I would like to keep it for `skype`).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, appearently I have to stream the audio via the http streaming feature in `mpd`. A couple links that might help you along:
http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=182574
http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=12352
http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Built-in_HTTP_streaming_part_2

Good Luck!